# Time tracker for lxde

Tags: 12.10, lxde, hamster

I have only recently started using lxde. And I am liking it. It is blazing fast, not-at-all resource hungry and just does what I want.

The only thing I am missing is a time tracker tool. I have been using Hamster Time Tracker on gnome for quite some time. In lxde, I can still launch the application. But there are no reminders when the time limit is up, etc. The time tracker is just another window.

Is there any way to get hamster working in lxde with notifications for time-up and an icon in the panel, etc.?

Alternatively, is there another application like Hamster that will do all that Hamster does and WORKS in lxde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. It took some trial and error. But the solution that worked finally is to launch `hamster-indicator` This puts an icon in the top panel. You can click the icon to look at how much time has elapsed on the current task. Moreover, on completion of the time specified, now there is a notification, too.

Auto-starting it is as easy as putting a .desktop file in .config/autostart folder.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look at Replicon's [time tracking software](http://www.replicon.com/time-tracking-softwares.aspx) which we have been using and after a detailed research and analysis for such tool while we switched to this one which seems to be one of the simplest and hassle free cloud based application with so many usability features.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution in Hampster wasn't what you were looking for, I'd also suggest looking at TSheets [time tracking software](http://www.tsheets.com/). Sounds like this app has the alerts and notifications you're looking for.